# Comparing String to class name

Tags: vb.net

I have a little Problem:
I have a method that parses an incoming string for certain values, if a value is found, a new class is instantiated. The class name is identical to the parsed string. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
Public Class Test1
End Class

Public Class Important
End Class

Public Class DoWork
Public Sub DoWork(incoming as String)
Select case incoming
case "Test1"
dim myobj as new Test1
Case "Important"
dim myobj as new Important
End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

I do not like the string literals like "Test1" - i could store them in a constant, but if the class names change, they have to be changed too. Is there a way to replace the literals with the Name of class?
I know that me.gettype produces the result for instantiated objects, but what about the simple name for a class, which is no object at this moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is in correct format you can use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-6) method to retrieve type. Then you can use [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to create instance if you have default constructor on that type.

Comment: I am not sure if this is any better, the String literal still exists in Type.GetType("Test1").Name :/

Comment: @ChristianSauer: No, you do: Type.GetType (incoming)

Comment: Note, though, that you're going to need the fully qualified class name, namespace included, for `Type.GetType()` to work. Also, it is case-sensitive, even if VB.NET isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Rafal's answer is good if you're stuck with the current situation, with the incoming string parameter. But it's still a bit fragile. What if the incoming parameter changes? What if you want to restructure your code, moving some classes to different namespaces or assemblies? What if those strings change - do you now have to rename your classes and recompile? You don't see the magic strings explicitly now, but they're still there.

So ask yourself - where are those strings coming from? Are they generated internally by your code? If so, you might want to generate, instead of strings, an Enum value that corresponds to the class to be instantiated. If they're external strings that you map to your classes, consider having explicit mapping (in a configuration file, for instance) that map String->Type. It's a bit more cumbersome, but a lot more flexible.

Comment: They are external strings - but they are under my control. But you are certainly right - this is a fragile solution. Do you have an Idea how such a config file could like?

Comment: A simple list of key-value pairs, with the incoming string as the key and the full type name as the value, should be simplest. There are a lot of resources out there on building custom configuration sections for your app.config file, though I have to admit the whole process is a bit more cumbersome than it has to be. Here's one: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx